# How to solve this error "tar: /tmp: Cannot open: Permission denied" during the app build phase in openshift origin

Tags: docker, openshift, centos7, openshift-origin

creating an application from an openshift template catalogs after successful installation of multi-masters hosts on GCP thrown this error during the build phase of the application:

```
Cloning "https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-ex.git " ...
    Commit: fbda3d301f534128de359962569117e576dd155a (Merge pull request #89 from bparees/interval)
    Author: Ben Parees <bparees@users.noreply.github.com>
    Date:   Fri Jan 19 11:50:17 2018 -0500
tar: /tmp: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
ERROR: Error copying file "/tmp/upload/src/.git/objects/pack/pack-33ae8e32ac7976585b2c18880e7c38cd98a2f0dd.pack" to tar: io: read/write on closed pipe
ERROR: Error writing tar: io: read/write on closed pipe
error: build error: write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
```

I need some bits of advice how to fix this problem. I have also tried with another template from the catalog like Node.js and I got the 
same problem

```
Cloning "https://github.com/openshift/nodejs-ex.git " ...
    Commit: ef1b71a300b58a35f37acfa69f871fc18075669d (Merge pull request #160 from aliok/patch-1)
    Author: Ben Parees <bparees@users.noreply.github.com>
    Date:   Fri Jan 12 10:16:26 2018 -0500
tar: /tmp: Cannot open: Permission denied
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
error: build error: read unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: read: connection reset by peer
```

Info about my environment on GCP:

```
- Centos 7
- 3 Masters w/ etcd & 2 Infras & 2 Nodes
  + OpenShift Master: v3.7.0+7ed6862
  + Kubernetes Master: v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62
  + Docker
docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.12.6
 API version:     1.24
 Package version: docker-1.12.6-71.git3e8e77d.el7.centos.1.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.8.3
 Git commit:      3e8e77d/1.12.6
 Built:           Tue Jan 30 09:17:00 2018
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Thank you for your support

Answer (score 1):

Permisions of `/tmp` directory should have read/write access.

```bash
chmod -R 755 /tmp
```

Comment: @Graham Dumpleton :This might resolve your errors.Can you share us the permissions available for /tmp directory

Comment: It isn't my problem and it is unlikely to be that simple. Doing ``chmod -R 755 /tmp`` is actually a bad idea. If you do that as root on a normal UNIX system, you could screw up operation of services with temporary files under ``/tmp`` if permissions are important.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton - Agree. `/tmp` was never meant for for doing chmod.

Comment: problem solved now. after troubleshooting w/ a friend and setting setenforce to 0 for all nodes with command `anssible nodes -a 'setenforce 0` , we were able to build application.

Answer (score 0):

So you did **not solve** the problem, you worked-around by disabling SELinux.

I once had the same problem. Root-cause: reuse of Docker repo.

What happened: I re-installed RHEL on a node *without* recreating the local Docker repository, thus instead of running docker-storage-setup again after the OS re-installation I reused the still existing Docker repo /var/lib/docker containing all the images pulled before, but this resulted in some SELinux mismatches, so the started containers were not able to write anywhere, not even in the container's /tmp.

Solution: delete & recreate the local Docker repository /var/lib/docker by (re-) running docker-storage-setup. (No need to disable SELinux.)